# Lambda expression vs anonymous methods

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-methods

I would like to know what is the difference. Currently I am learning this stuff and it seems to me like these are just the same:

```
delegate void X();

X instanceOfX;

instanceOfX = delegate() { code };

instanceOfX = () => { code };
```

Also if the lambda are newer, should I just use lambda and forget on anonymous methods?

Comment: Think in terms of evolution of the language. In C# 1, we had delegates. In C# 2, they added anonymous methods. C# 3 added lambdas. Easier ways to accomplish similar tasks. For more on the evolution, I would encourage you to check out the book *C# In Depth*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, lambda expressions are just very special anonymous methods.

However, there are some deep differences. Start with Eric Lippert's [Lambda Expression vs. Anonymous Methods, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx) and continue to the rest of the [series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/lambda+expressions/).

Comment: So what's special about them?

Comment: What is special about them<? thanks

Comment: @recursive for a start, one MAJOR difference is that single line Lambdas can be assigned to an Expression tree whereas Anonymous methods cannot.

Comment: I prefer anonymous method, I'm not always using linq otherwise I like use FindAll from List.

Answer (score 4):

The only difference is the lambda can be easily cast to `Expression<Func<void>>`. The delegates are purely just methods/closures, but the lambda can also be broken down into an expression tree:

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> expr = x => x*2; // Expression tree
Func<int, int> fun = x => x*2;              // Function
delegate int MyDelegate(int x);             // Delegate
MyDelegate del = x => x*2;                  // Same as Function and Delegate
```

Comment: Note that this is only possible for a subset of lamdas: Expression-lamdas but not statement lamdas.

Comment: Note that "Delegate" is a terrible name for a delegate type because it will be easily confused with System.Delegate, its base class.

Comment: I apologize. I'm still drinking coffee this morning and I honestly couldn't think of another name