# Can someone tell me how to fix this error on C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am a beginner to C# and I am getting this error `Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Action'`. I honestly do not know how to fix this. if you could help me please tell me what I should add to my code to fix this error. I am basically writing a Unit Test that will test if the code is working correctly (the code is supposed to throw an exception). This is my code:

Unit Test Project File:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void ExceptionTest()
    {
        var test = new JumpingCode();
        Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentException>(test.EmptyValue(null));
    }
```

The Class File:

```
namespace Jumping
{
    public class JumpingCode
    {
      public string EmptyValue(string some)
      {
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(some))
          {
            throw new ArgumentException("Name Cannot be null or empty");
          }

          return "Hello World";
      }

   }
}
```

I am basically testing a random throw. The Unit Test file is the one throwing the error messages. The error messages are on this line `Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentException>(test.EmptyValue(null))` the `test.EmptyValue(null)`is the text that is underlined. I honestly have no idea what is the problem. I know I am doing something wrong but I just don't know what. I don't know if this will change anything but I have never wrote a unit test for an exception before.

Answer (score 4):

You're passing the result of `EmptyValue` (a `string`) to `Assert.ThrowsException` but this method expects an [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) to be validated.

You have to change this

```
Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentException>(test.EmptyValue(null));
```

by this

```
Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentException>(() => test.EmptyValue(null));
```

Comment: Your amazing thank you very much. Can you please explain to me how and why this works now?

Comment: In your code, you're passing the return value of `EmpyValue` to your `Assert` method, which is a `string`. 
But `Assert` requires a `Action` delegate (method call) as a parameter, which this lambda expression creates. For more info, click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934544/lambda-expression-vs-anonymous-methods).

Comment: Assert.ThrowsException<...> expects an 'Action' Delegate (which does not return a result). Your 'EmptyValue' method is not compatible with an 'Action' because it returns a string.
By encapsulation the method call in a lambda expression that discards the return type, you are actually passing an 'Action' to the Assert method.

Comment: @jAC: Johan provided some extra information, let me know if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Assert.Throws returns the exception that's thrown which lets you assert on the exception

So in case no exception is thrown, or an exception of the wrong type is thrown, the first Assert Throws assertion will fail.

BUT if an exception of the correct type is thrown then you can now assert on the actual exception that you've saved in the variable.

You have to write it like this

```
var ex = Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => foo.Bar(null));
```

So in your case

```
var ext = Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentException>(() =>test.EmptyValue(null));
```

Comment: Please accept my answer or upvote or both if you believe I helped